# Can't sign in Goolge Play Game Services: Must have a game ID to sign in

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am trying to integrate Google Play Game Services but can't sign in. I know some developers ask about this problem before but the problem is nobody asked about the error I am encountering.

The log is this.

> Must have a game ID to sign in!
>
> Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 12501, resolution=null}
>
> Invalid (empty) game ID found in the EXTRA_GAME_ID extra.

I was just following the tutorial on the official doc.
What is the cause of this error possibly? Seems like no one asked about this error and it's weird. Everyone got some status code but mine is just `unknown`
Anyone have encountered this error?

## Code

`Manifest`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="...">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    ...
```

`Activity`

```
private void startSignInIntent() {
    GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
            GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
    Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // The signed in account is stored in the result.
            GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
        } else {
            String message = result.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
            if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
                Log.e("e", result.getStatus());
                message = "Something wrong happened. Please try again.";
            }
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.CustomAlertDialogTheme).setMessage(message)
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null).show();
        }
    }
}
```

`res/values/ids.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="app_id" type="string">digits here...</item>
</resources>
```

I am sure I linked my app to Play Game Services. I added myself to tester on Play Console (Game Services section as well as Release management). I tried with both actual device and emulator. I didn't create OAuth2 client ID manually on API Console. I created it from Play Console. SHA-1 is correct (If this is incorrect I am supposed to get other error message.) Never worked.

Comment: so how we suppose to know what you have written? care to share? specially that sign in part?

Comment: @Sam. Sorry I updated now. Please take a look but I actually post this question three times with code and process but nobody answered. I think I made a mistake in other basic part.

Comment: your code looks okay to me.. you included that only 12 digit in app id right?

Comment: @Sam. Yes only digits part. I am just looking for someone who encountered this error because nobody can answer..

Comment: Sometimes applicationId of build.gralde doesn't match with a registered id. Please check your console and your android studio carefully. A very small difference can make the problem. make sure all details in console and app matches.. Or try deleting it from console and make a new start.. in case.

Comment: I'm facing same problem, have you found solution to this problem?

Comment: @kubaork No.. I currently give up implementing Google Play Games..

Answer (score 1):

I came across problem with same output - I downgraded version of com.google.android.gms:play-services-(base/games/auth) to 16.0.0 and got better error log:

```
019-10-24 11:52:03.266 25880-12410/? E/ValidateServiceOp: ****
**** APP ID IS NOT CORRECTLY CONFIGURED TO USE GOOGLE PLAY GAME SERVICES
**** Specify it using @string resources value or \u003 followed by an app_id value.
**** For example:
****   meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
****             android:value="@string/app_id" />
**** or
****   meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
****             android:value="\u003123456789" />
```

My manifest was like this:

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
****             android:value="3123456789" />
```

I had missing `\u003` symbol. After replacing this with `@string/app_id` and putting value to strings.xml it started working. You added this string to `ids.xml`, which may be wrong.

After doing that I upgraded version of Google Play Services and everything works!