# Google sign in for game failed

Tags: android, game-engine, google-signin

Please, I need help because sure it is silly but I'm a bit stuck.
I have an already functional android game in play store but I want to incorporate a leaderboard and for this I need users to enter their google username for google games. I have read the manuals many times and surely I am missing something.
To give you a little context, the game is already published in playstore, the game is also associated with playgames, the leaderboaard is created in google games, the game is linked to firebase and I have the apis created. (I would say everything well done). I have also incorporated the .json. And I am testing it in the emulator of Android Studio in debug mode.
If I use this code I get the following error:

```
 GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("My id client")
            .requestScopes(Games.SCOPE_GAMES_LITE)
            .build();
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(MainActivity.this, gso);
```

2020-04-07 12:40:52.641 11274-12521/? E/SignInAuthenticator: ****

```
**** APP NOT CORRECTLY CONFIGURED TO USE GOOGLE PLAY GAME SERVICES
**** This is usually caused by one of these reasons:
**** (1) Your package name and certificate fingerprint do not match
****     the client ID you registered in Developer Console.
**** (2) Your App ID was incorrectly entered.
**** (3) Your game settings have not been published and you are 
****     trying to log in with an account that is not listed as
****     a test account.
****
**** To help you debug, here is the information about this app
**** Package name         : info_hiden
**** Cert SHA1 fingerprint: info_hiden
**** App ID from manifest : info_hiden
****
**** Check that the above information matches your setup in 
**** Developer Console. Also, check that you're logging in with the
**** right account (it should be listed in the Testers section if
**** your project is not yet published).
****
**** For more information, refer to the troubleshooting guide:
****   http://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting
```

When I say "My clien id, I get it from here:

[Client ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZyTd.jpg)

Is this correct? Should I check more things? By the way I do have the ids of the game in the manifest and I have everything implemented in the graddle.

Should i do something additional in firebase? Honestly, I'm not even clear what firebase is for.

Ah, if I put the previous code but without the IdToken line I can enter my google user without problem to the application, only afterwards it won't let me show anything on the leaderboard because it tells me that there is no associated client and the key is missing, which is normal i guess. From what I understand I must have the problem in the key. Is that so?

Thank you very much for your help!

** EDIT:

I am now trying with this ID:

[Client ID new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irEit.jpg)

And it seems that it sign i well but I have this log:

```
2020-04-07 18:22:24.550 1658-2174/? W/AppOps: Bad call: specified package com.google.android.play.games under uid 10013 but it is really 10156
    java.lang.RuntimeException: here
        at com.android.server.AppOpsService.getOpsRawLocked(AppOpsService.java:1257)
        at com.android.server.AppOpsService.checkPackage(AppOpsService.java:976)
        at com.android.internal.app.IAppOpsService$Stub.onTransact(IAppOpsService.java:169)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
2020-04-07 18:22:24.564 26592-26592/? W/ChimeraUtils: Non Chimera context
2020-04-07 18:22:24.586 26592-26651/? W/GLSUser: [DeviceKeyStore] Cannot load key: Device key file not found.
2020-04-07 18:22:24.596 11274-11371/? W/GamesServiceBroker: Client connected with SDK 201000000, Services 200914022, and Games 168400078
```

And:

```
2020-04-07 18:22:24.781 26592-26651/? W/GLSUser: [AppCertManager] IOException while requesting key: 
    java.io.IOException: Invalid device key response.
        at ipd.a(:com.google.android.gms@200914022@20.09.14 (040700-300565878):46)
        at ipb.a(:com.google.android.gms@200914022@20.09.14 (040700-300565878):5)
        at ipb.a(:com.google.android.gms@200914022@20.09.14 (040700-300565878):42)
        at clb.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@200914022@20.09.14 (040700-300565878):6)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
        at dtz.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@200914022@20.09.14 (040700-300565878):2)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
        at aaml.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@200914022@20.09.14 (040700-300565878):26)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
2020-04-07 18:22:24.781 26592-26651/? W/GLSUser: [DeviceKeyStore] Cannot load key: Device key file not found.
```

And:

```
2020-04-07 18:22:25.153 11274-11365/? E/Volley: [18347] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/applications/played
2020-04-07 18:22:25.165 11274-23833/? W/GameAgent: Volley error when reporting played
    com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@200914022@20.09.14 (040700-300565878):37)
        at stl.performRequest(:com.google.android.gms@200914022@20.09.14 (040700-300565878):14)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.a(:com.google.android.gms@200914022@20.09.14 (040700-300565878):6)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(:com.google.android.gms@200914022@20.09.14 (040700-300565878):2)
```

Any idea please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to simply sign in to Google Play game services, then you should specify `GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN` and you should *not* request scopes or a real ID token.  (See https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInOptions)

Regarding the game services configuration issue, most likely the issue is, as the error message states, caused by one of those three reasons (which in turn is causing the authentication problem for the later games API request).  (See https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#avoiding_common_setup_problems for detailed information.)

The first Client ID image you showed seems correctly configured, so let's analyze each of the components one by one.  (The second client ID page you linked is not for an Android app, and won't be used by Google Play game services on Android).

First, look at your game's Game Services page in the Google Play Developer Console.  There should be a green check mark next to "Linked Apps" and "Testing" in the sidebar to the left.  If either of those is not green, ensure you've linked an app with the same package name as shown on the OAuth client ID page, and that you've saved information on the testing page, etc.

Ensure that the package name listed on the Client ID page is the same as the package name in your game's AndroidManifest.xml (and matches the package name listed in the error message).

Next make sure that your game is signed correctly.  The SHA-1 fingerprint from the error message must match the fingerprint shown on the Client ID page.  Note that if your app signing is managed by Google Play, you may not have access to the key used to sign apps for distribution from Google Play (it may not be the same as your upload key depending on how you set up the app in Google Play).

The APP ID refers to the Google Play Games application ID (not the full OAuth client ID).  It is found on the Google Play Developer Console Game Services page for your game.  It will be a 12 or 13 digit number directly underneath your game's title on the game services page, and it's also the first component of the OAuth client IDs that you highlighted.  *Make sure that the APP ID from manifest listed in the error message matches the number listed on the game's game services page in the developer console.*  If the app ID is missing entirely, ensure that your game's AndroidManifest.xml contains a `<meta-data>` element defining the APP ID within its `<application>` section, and that the ID starts with `\u003` or is contained in a resource.  (See [Can't sign in Goolge Play Game Services: Must have a game ID to sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57535377/cant-sign-in-goolge-play-game-services-must-have-a-game-id-to-sign-in))

Finally, ensure that the default Google account on your device is listed in the Testers section of the Game Services page for your app.  On a device with multiple Google accounts, one of them may be set to "automatically sign in to supported games".

Hope one of those things identifies the problem.